In my flutter app, while using checkout_screen_ui widget and I am getting $ in front of product prices but I want Indian rupees sign '₹'
I am working a flutter project that is an ecommerce app that sells sneakers. In my checkout page I have used the checkout_screen_ui widget version 1.0.1 which a prebuild widget by flutter. While using the widget I am getting '$' in front of product prices but I want Indian rupees sign '₹'.
Checkout Page
I tried formatting the $ symbol by ₹ manually in the code but it still doesn't work.
class paymenTpage extends StatefulWidget {
  paymenTpage({super.key, required this.orderedShoes, required this.quant});

  List<Sneakers> orderedShoes;
  List<String> quant;

  @override
  State<paymenTpage> createState() => _paymenTpageState();
}

class _paymenTpageState extends State<paymenTpage> {
  final List<PriceItem> _priceItems = [];

  void setData() {
    int index = 0;
    for (var element in widget.orderedShoes) {
      double productPrice = double.parse(element.price);
      int totalPriceInCents =
          (productPrice * 100).round(); // Multiply by 100 to convert to cents
      int quantity = int.parse(widget.quant[index]);

      String formattedPrice =
          '\u{20B9}${productPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)}'; // Add rupee symbol and format
      print("Formatted Price: $formattedPrice");

      _priceItems.add(
        PriceItem(
          name: element.name,
          quantity: quantity,
          itemCostCents: totalPriceInCents,
          description: formattedPrice,
        ),
      );
      print("Description of added PriceItem: ${_priceItems.last.description}");
      index++;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  void Function(CheckOutResult)? onNativePay;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // implement initState
    super.initState();
    setData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey.shade100, // Navigation bar
          statusBarColor: Colors.grey.shade100, // Status bar
        ),
      ),
      body: CheckoutPage(
        data: CheckoutData(
          priceItems: _priceItems,
          payToName: 'Atharva Enterprises',
          onCardPay: (cardformresults, checkoutresult) =>
              print('Credit card : $CardFormResults, $CheckOutResult'),
          onNativePay: (checkoutresult) {
            int index = 0;
            // ignore: avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls
            widget.orderedShoes.forEach((element) async {
              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("users")
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
                  .collection("ordered")
                  .add({
                "id": element.id,
                "gend": element.category,
                "paid": "true",
                "delivered": "pending",
                "amount":
                    "${(int.parse(element.price) * int.parse(widget.quant[index]))}",
              });
              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("users")
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
                  .collection("shoes")
                  .doc(element.id)
                  .update({"cart": "false", "quantity": "1"});
            });
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const successfull()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Does your CheckoutPage actually use the description of the items? Maybe you actually hardcoded them to dollar signs in that page

It is hardcoded in the library.

Ah I totally missed it was a package that made the UI. Yeah, it's hardcoded in there. I guess the only way to fix it is to make your own UI. Possibly just copy pasting the code from the package and adjusting it to your needs

It should be fairly straightforward to fork the repository, change the currency symbol to the one you wish to use, and add it as a git package dependency.
